# netbeans Run error :Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, mojo

I'm very new to net-beans 8.0.2 and want to run java example but theres error below after Run:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project MachineLearning: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

and this is the pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.artificog</groupId>
    <artifactId>MachineLearning</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-math</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

am i need to install something?
any help appreciated.

-thanks

edit: turn off net-beans and turn on anaconda solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message will be displayed whenever it fails to run for any reason. It is preceded by error messages that are more specific. So for more information just scroll up.

Most likely it is a build error, so find the red lines on the right side of editor window for each source file that has a red exclamation point on it in the projects tab and fix those lines.

Comment: thanks for your reply,there was exclamation mark on JDBC connection line that i pass install,create db and successful connection steps,for now there's no error but still build is failure :  Starting the program ...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
 at com.artificog.machinelearning.Main.run(Main.java:60)
 at com.artificog.machinelearning.Main.main(Main.java:42)
BUILD FAILURE           what to do?+thanks